# C++ class copy constructor

Tags: c++, class, vector, copy-constructor

I am having erratic issue with my copy constructor.

I have a class MyData as follows:

```
class MyData
{
    private:
    std::vector<double> wavelength;
    std::vector<double> amplitude;

    public:
    MyData::MyData(void) {}

    MyData::MyData(const MyData &cSource)
      : wavelength(cSource.wavelength), amplitude(cSource.amplitude)
    {}
}
```

In my main program, I am inserting MyData objects into a ring buffer. This is how I am reading it back in main:

```
MyData data;
data = removeq(&q);
```

The problem is that sometimes the copied data is missing some values. Etc. if the original size of wavelength is 1, the copied data shows 0. I have debugged my program and the data in the ring buffer is correct etc it shows the correct size of 1.

Anyone have any idea if my copy constructor is wrong or do i need an assignment operator overload ??

Thanks!

The code i used for insert/remove into ring buffer:

```
void insertq(struct queue *p, MyData v)
{
    int t;
    t = (p->rear+1)%MAX;
    if(t == p->front)
    {   }
    else
    {
            p->rear = t;        
            p->arr[p->rear] = v;
    }
}
MyData removeq(struct queue *p)
{
    MyData empty;   

    if(isempty(p))
    {               
        return empty;
    }
    else
    {       
        p->front = (p->front + 1)%MAX;
        empty = p->arr[p->front];
        return empty;
    }
 }
```

Comment: The copy constructor is fine (it's identical to the one the compiler would have autogenerated, btw). The problem lies in `removeq()` and its design -- how do you expect to call the copy constructor on an object that's already been constructed? Show us how you use the copy constructor in `removeq`.

Comment: You don't need to explicitly write copy ctor here, the default one will do the same thing.

Comment: Did you try adding the assignment overload? It would take only a minute or two to write and test. The copy constructor looks OK. It might help if you post some more of the relevant code.

Comment: @fileoffset while the assignment operator is the thing that's being called, the default assignment operator is fine if two `vector`s is really what composes his class. Actually he doesn't need _any_ functions in this class at all.

Comment: Agreed, so long as the class is truly POD. I had a feeling the code is not entirely all shown ;)

Comment: It is an error to qualify the member with the class name *inside* the class definition. Both constructors should be `MyData(void)` and `MyData(const MyData& cSource)` [or you could remove them altogether as the compiler generated ones are equivalent, also note the rule of the three there: if you *need* (not the case) to provide one of destructor, copy constructor or assignment operator you probably need all three -- in this case none of them is needed].

Comment: Also note that use of the `(void)` parameter list is deprecated.  It was necessary in C, or else the compiler would interpret `f()` as a function that accepts any number of arguments.  In C++, it is redundant (and ugly).

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the reply! I have removed the constructors as suggested since there is no point having them written out.

Comment: shouldn't you read from the buffer *before* advancing the pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the advice. I have removed the copy constructor and assignment overload methods as suggested.

The issue was with the circular buffer structure I used. I changed the circular buffer code to this example here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43510/Lock-Free-Single-Producer-Single-Consumer-Circular

and it worked. There seem to be no more errors. I had initially thought that the problem was due to the copy or assignment operator as the error was intermittent and so I did not check if it was the circular buffer that was causing the error.

Answer (score 2):

In order to call the copy constructor you have to declare and initialize your object (using another object) in the same line. Your current code actually calls the overloaded = operator.

Comment: To add more details, you should write `MyData data(removeq(&q));` or you should implement `MyData& operator=(const MyData& other);`.

Comment: agreed :) will do from next time onwards

Answer (score 2):

A copy constructor is called when you create a new object from an existing object. Here, you are calling the assignment operator:

```
MyData data;
data = removeq(&q);
```

If you had used

```
 Data oldDataObject;
 Data newDataObject = oldDataObject;
```

the copy constructor will get invoked.

In the context of your code, you should override the '=' operator to solve this.

```
MyData& operator = (const MyData& data);
```